# using bash or python to compare two files content

Tags: python, shell

i'm looking for a way to create a new file (c.txt), with contents of b.txt file column and contents of a.txt file.

In shell or in python.

Here is an exemple, maybe it will be more clear...

This is the a.txt file:

```
# Ansible managed
#########################################################
# date : 20220125T094050
# profile name : zoneA
# role version : v0.0.6
#
#########################################################
# security ID    |   default   |    custom   |   applied   |
# rule_a_10      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_a_12      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_a_13      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_b_01      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_c_01      |           1 |             |           1 |
```

This is the b.txt file:

```
# Ansible managed
#########################################################
# date : 20220125T114050
# profile name : zoneB
# role version : v0.0.7
#
#########################################################
# security ID    |   default   |    custom   |   applied   |
# rule_a_10      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_a_12      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_a_13      |          -1 |           0 |           0 |
# rule_b_01      |          -1 |           1 |           1 |
# rule_d_01      |          -1 |           1 |           1 |
```

I'm looking to have a c.txt file with this content, if values are in the custom column:

```
# Ansible managed
#########################################################
# date : 20220125T094050  => date from A file
# profile name : zoneA    => zone from A file 
# role version : v0.0.6   => version from B file
#
#########################################################
# security ID    |   default   |    custom   |   applied   |
# rule_a_10      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_a_12      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_a_13      |          -1 |           0 |           0 |
# rule_b_01      |          -1 |           1 |           1 |
# rule_c_01      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_d_01      |          -1 |           1 |           1 |
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you have tried to accomplish this task so that the community can analyze it along with your issue.

Comment: "in shell or Python" is a good clue that a question isn't on-topic here at all. You're supposed to come to us with a shell problem or a Python problem or otherwise some _narrow, specific technical issue_ that you ran into while writing a program yourself, not a specification for a program you never even picked an implementation language for.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is not a question. If you're looking for help with writing this code, then what have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? SO is not a code-writing service; you need to try to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas makes your code less eye straining.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


a_txt = '''# Ansible managed
#########################################################
# date : 20220125T094050
# profile name : zoneA
# role version : v0.0.6
#
#########################################################
# security ID    |   default   |    custom   |   applied   |
# rule_a_10      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_a_12      |           1 |             |           1 |
# rule_a_13      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_b_01      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_c_01      |           1 |             |           1 |
'''

b_txt = '''# Ansible managed
#########################################################
# date : 20220125T114050
# profile name : zoneB
# role version : v0.0.7
#
#########################################################
# security ID    |   default   |    custom   |   applied   |
# rule_a_10      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_a_12      |          -1 |             |          -1 |
# rule_a_13      |          -1 |           0 |           0 |
# rule_b_01      |          -1 |           1 |           1 |
# rule_d_01      |          -1 |           1 |           1 |
'''

dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a_txt), sep='|', header=7, dtype=object)
dfb = pd.read_csv(StringIO(b_txt), sep='|', header=7, dtype=object)

# custom: find number
t_b = dfb.loc[dfb.iloc[:, 2].str.match('.*\d.*')]

dft = pd.merge(dfa.iloc[:, 0], t_b.iloc[:, 0], how='outer', indicator=True)

# A only
t_a = pd.merge(dft.loc[dft.iloc[:, 1] == 'left_only'].iloc[:, 0], dfa, how='inner', on=dft.columns[0])

# B only or A/B both(use B)
t_b = pd.merge(dft.loc[dft.iloc[:, 1] != 'left_only'].iloc[:, 0], dfb, how='inner', on=dft.columns[0])

# A only + B only + A/B both(use B)
df = pd.concat([t_a, t_b])

# sort by security ID
df = df.sort_values(by=[df.columns[0]])

# not necessary but not remove/drop (for last sep(|))
df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 4': ''}, axis=1)

# c_txt = '/path/c.txt'
c_txt = StringIO()
df.to_csv(c_txt, sep='|', index=False)
print(c_txt.getvalue())
```

Comment: As a note for the future, a question that doesn't specify a narrow, specific technical problem the OP encountered while trying to write software _themselves_ is typically off-topic here and shouldn't be answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).